# Probability Distribution on unit circle

Tags: probability

I currently stuck at following task:
So I have a probability distribution:
$$
f^{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi}\; \forall(x,y)\in A
$$
where $$
A = \{ (x,y) : x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \}
$$

-I now want to calculate the Variance(X), Variance(Y) and the Covariance(X,Y). I know that Cov(X,Y) = 0, but how do I show this ?

-Also I want to show that X and Y are not indipendent. I mean intuitively it is pretty clear that X and Y are dependent of each other, but how do i show it mathematically? So obviously i need to show that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X\cap Y) =\mathbb{P}(X)\mathbb{P}(Y)
$$
but how ?

Answer (score 0):

Hints: covariance can easily be calculated using polar coordinates: $cov(X,Y)=\int_0^{1} \int_0^{2\pi} (r\cos \, \theta)(r\sin \, \theta) rdrd\theta$. To show that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent consider $\{Y>\frac 1 2\}$ and $\{|X| \leq\frac {\sqrt 3} 2\}$. Note that $X^{2}+Y^{2} \leq 1$ so $Y>\frac 1 2$ implies $|X| \leq\frac {\sqrt 3} 2$. If $X$ and $Y$ were independent we would have $P\{Y>\frac 1 2\}P\{|X| \leq\frac {\sqrt 3} 2\}=P\{ Y>\frac 1 2,|X| \leq\frac {\sqrt 3} 2\}$. But the right side is simply $P\{Y>\frac 1 2\}$. So the equation becomes $P\{|X| \leq\frac {\sqrt 3} 2\}=1$ (because $P\{Y>\frac 1 2\} \neq 0$). Can you check that this is a contardiction? (Use polar coordinates for all probabilities).

Comment: But in order to calculate Var(x) and Var(y) i first have to calculate the marginal distributions right ? So that I have:
$$
\mathbb{E}(X) = \int x f^X(x) dx 
$$
and then I substitute $ x = r \cdot cos(\theta)$ right ?

Comment: $Var(X)=\int_A x^{2} \frac 1 {\pi} dxdy$ which can be calculated easily using polar coordinates. (Note that $EX=EY=0$ by symmetry).

Comment: @RedCrayon The formula $Eg(X,Y) =\int \int  g(x,y) f_{X,Y}dxdy$ can be used when $g(x,y)$ depends only on one variable (like $g(x,y)=x^{2})$. So you can find $var (X)$ without calculating the density of $X$.